# Python: Title per histogram in pandas dataframe.hist?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, histogram

This may be a very easy question, but I can not find the answer anywhere. When you have a pandas dataframe in Python and you plot histograms per column of values, how is it then possible to change the title per plot in stead of the standard titles (0, 1, 2, etc.).

When you have this for example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import seaborn as sns

values = np.random.randn(10,5)
df = DataFrame(values)
df.hist()
sns.plt.show()
```

You get the following result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest is set column names of `DataFrame`:

```
values = np.random.randn(10,5)
names= ['a','b','c','d','e']
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=names)
df.hist()
sns.plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was searching for! Nevertheless I find it still weird that you can't specify titles in the hist()-function.

Comment: Yes, I try find some solution, but unfortunately `df.hist(title=names)` failed.

Comment: Do you also know how to manipulate titlesize while using the df.hist() command?

(I know how to do it without df.hist() but it always surprises me that something like df.hist(titlesize=20) does not work..)